# Maven/Spring multi module project logging

Tags: spring, logging, slf4j

I am trying to convert a huge maven/spring webapp to a multi module project.

Logging is implemented with this method (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-logging-slf4j) in the huge project. What is the correct way to do this in a maven multi module project? Is it necessary to define this in every `pom.xml` or only in my main `pom.xml`.

My main `pom.xml` defines this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-framework-bom</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
</dependency>
```

Is it possibly to exclude `commons-logging` on this dependency?

Update:

The project structure:

- Parent Project:

  - Project A: jar
  - Project B: jar
  - Project C: war
  - Project D: war

All projects using parts of the Spring framework. I am using SLF4J for logging. What is the correct way for including SLF4J in this project setup with maven?

Answer (score 0):

It should only be necessary to exclude commons-logging from "spring-core", but some third-party libraries also include it, so that isn't always enough. You could try using Spring Boot starters to build up your Spring dependencies (even if you aren't using other Boot features), since the default logging system is logback and commons-logging has been carefully excluded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am using SLF4J in my huge project. So the huge project has the four dependencies `jcl-over-slf4j`, `slf4j-api`, `slf4j-log4j12` and `log4j`. What dependencies are now neccessary for my multi modules? Two are webapps and others are jars. All are using parts of the Spring framework.

Comment: You probably need logging in all of them, don't you? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: I updated my description. Of course i am using logging in all of them. :) I am not sure where i need which dependency for logging.

Comment: If you need those dependencies in all the modules you can add them to the parent. That seems pretty obvious, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something. Maybe you should start again, and rephrase your question as "I did this, and this happened. How do I make it do that instead?"

Comment: I have a similar question, perhaps this will trigger a response: Change from one project (no module) to a POM project with multiple modules. Dependencies can go to the parent, where should the `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` go? I will give it a try, but I am not sure, if POM projects are allowed to have resources ...